# Proving the property of a linear operator (PDE)

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-differential-equations

Use special cases of linear operator such as $L=x$ and $M=\frac{\partial }{\partial x}$ to show that the product $LM$ and $ML$ are not always the same.

What i tried

What i have to show is that

$$L(M(c_{1}u_{1}))\neq M(L(c_{1}u_{1}))$$
Thus Let 
$$c_{1}u_{1}=3x^2+5x$$
and we have to show that

$$x(\frac{\partial }{\partial x}(c_{1}u_{1}))\neq \frac{\partial }{\partial x}(x(c_{1}u_{1}))$$

$$x(\frac{\partial }{\partial x}(3x^2+5x))\neq \frac{\partial }{\partial x}(x(3x^2+5x))$$

Calculating both sides of the equation we can clearly see that they are not equal. Is my solution correct. Could anyone explain. Thanks

Comment: What you're being asked to do here is show that linear operators need not commute. This is the same as showing that there exist a pair of linear operators, $L$ and $M$, such that $LM\neq ML$. You chose $L=x$ and $M=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ as candidate operators and showed that, yes indeed, the do not commute. (i.e. you found an $L$ and $M$ that don't commute, and showed that they don't commute).

Comment: So what i did was correct?

Comment: yes, exactly correct. One of many possible ways to answer the question (disproving things in general usually comes down to merely finding *a* counterexample (and ofc, showing that it is, in fact a counterexample), and there are often many possible counterexamples).